# Massive load time of over 15 secs of React App on Mobile browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobile, browser

I have deployed an app on React but the load time on mobile browsers is over 17 secs? and on web is about 6 seconds. Not sure where to look at is it an issue with setup, compresion or the theme used in building the platform. https://app.latom.in/co/getlocal

Any thoughts?

Thanks

Comment: It is working fine!

Comment: Thats good to know :), but many users are leaving before load! I use clarity and pagespeed to identify bounce rate - currently on pagespeed for mobile, profile loads in more than 15 secs, users leave in 3 secs :(

Comment: why do people still use react? Maybe its time to STOP?

Comment: ssr (next) or suspense maybe